# How to align text next to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how I can align text next to each other inside a column. What I tried is:

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-md-3 property">
        <div className="card shadow">
            <img className="card-img-top" alt="Image 1" src={("./Components/Images/slide-image1.jpg")}></img>
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">Info</h5>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <h3>$ 500</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <span className="badge badge-warning">Villa</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <button className="btn btn-details btn-sm text">View Details</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is a nested row but I cant get it working.
How can I align `$ 500 villa button` next to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need those extra columns. Just put all the text inside your row and put `float: left` on the elements.

Comment: Oh yes true.. Didn't know about float. Thank you

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can add this style

```
style="text-align:center;"
```